# How do login into SharePoint 2010 Online remotely via a C# Console Application?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to have a console app that can login in, authenticate and update some custom lists.  I can't find any good examples that work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only tricky part for accessing SharePoint Online from the Client Object Model will be the authentication. There is no direct method of authenticating with SharePoint Online from the CSOM so Microsoft has released a work around.

You can find the details and code here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjohnson/archive/2011/05/03/authentication-with-sharepoint-online-and-the-client-side-object-model.aspx

So what it basically does is:

1. Opens up a browser Instance
2. Authenticates with the browser
3. Grabs the authentication cookie and passes it to the Client Object Model.

The rest of the tasks should be quite straight forward. You can find many code samples here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537013.aspx

UPDATE:  You this technique to allow the authentication to happen without a human running the console app:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjohnson/archive/2011/05/14/part-2-headless-authentication-with-sharepoint-online-and-the-client-side-object-model.aspx

Comment: Where would I specify the login/password?  I don't see that in the example.  It gets through the process, but then gives me a 403 Access is denied.  I'm assuming because it's not authenticated properly.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the first link for the authentication sample? See here for direct jump to the page: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Remote-Authentication-in-b7b6f43c/sourcecode?fileId=21439&pathId=1168218626

Comment: Yes, that is what I am using.  Does the window that it puts up supposed to be where you manually login?  Is that how it gets it?   Mine just opens really fast then closes, but still.  If this requires user interactivity, then this won't work.

Comment: Yes you will have to login if you are not already authenticated with Internet Explorer. Once you log in, the cookie will be saved and you wont have to login again till it expires. My guess is that you are already logged in with a different account in IE and that's why the window is closing fast and you are getting the access denied error.

Comment: so for this technique to work, you have to have a user logging in?  Is there no way to authenticate with SP remotely with a nightly job.  I just want to keep a custom list in sync with a SQL table.

Comment: Here is a "headless" version based on CSOM.  Still trying to get that one to work as well.  I still get a 403.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjohnson/archive/2011/05/14/part-2-headless-authentication-with-sharepoint-online-and-the-client-side-object-model.aspx

Comment: Yup it sure is not straightforward. Thankfully it is fixed in SP 2013.

Answer (score 1):

If you will be running this console app on the SharePoint server then use the SharePoint Object Model.

On the other hand, if this app will be accessing SharePoint remotely then use CSOM. For information about how to use CSOM, see the following MS Pattern & Practices [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798388.aspx).

Basically, the way CSOM works is:

1. Create a context by specifying the SharePoint site.
2. Create a query.
3. Execute the query. Which will send that query to the SP server (more specifically to the  client.svc), execute the query, and return the result back to you.

Comment: This is SP 2010 online, so it wil be remote, not on that server.

Comment: Then, in that case use CSOM.